# How does PHP know what time it is?

Tags: algorithm, datetime

<sub>I'm using PHP as an example. I assume the process is similar for other languages as well. I'm not necessarily looking for answers limited to PHP.</sub>

---

I know PHP gets the Epoch data from the OS. But PHP has a [practically infinite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) number of way to format the date. How does it do it?

For something as simple as:

```
date('Y-m-d');
// i.e. "2017-11-20"
```

...is obviously some easy math (`epoch/1000/60/60/24/etc`). But how does it account for leap seconds? And what about when you get into the more unique formats such as:

```
date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
// i.e. "Monday 20th of November 2017 21:30:55 PM"
```

What algorithm does it use to figure out the day? Does it divide then count from the start of Epoch? What about the Meridian? Or month names? Or daylight savings time?

**How does a programming language know what the datetime is?**

Comment: If this is better asked on [softwareengineering.se], I am fine with either reposting there or having the question moved.

Comment: I guess PHP and other languages just call OS's date API and requests "desired" output.

Comment: The programming language will do the formatting and understand formats, but it is the OS which takes care of leap seconds, daylight saving. It is more complex to write a compiler for a programming language than to parse date/time formats and produce some datetime formats.

Comment: @Kyslik - I was under the impression that the OS only provided the epoch. Is that wrong?

Comment: I am no expert here :D just guessing, I ran `$ strace date` and will go dig some code up. Here is some code http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/src/src/bin/date/date.c

Comment: Many OS will synchronise regularly with some time service, which will provide the epoch time, which will already take into account leap seconds. PHP knows nothing about that.

Comment: @trincot - How then does PHP correctly render the date without being 25 seconds off? Surely it has to know that there are extra seconds to correctly determine the datetime.

Comment: No, those 25 seconds are lost between the times that the OS synchronises with a time server. Let's say the time between two syncs is 1000 seconds, and there is a leap second removed during that time, then the time server will give an epoch time that is just 999 more than the previous one. The OS just takes it as it comes. And PHP just takes it from the OS whenever it needs to know what time it is.

Answer (score 0):

The full answer to this question is ... long and complicated. For a good detailed explanation, see [The UNIX leap second mess](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/unix-leap-seconds.html).

That covers UNIX time stamps, but the issue is basically the same regardless of the operating system, and has to do with what exactly a timestamp means. Conventional wisdom is that it's the number of milliseconds since the Epoch date. But by the time the programming library you're working with gets it, it's actually the number of milliseconds since the Epoch date, *excluding leap seconds*.

The linked article goes into how the standard changed to include leap seconds, and depend on the timezone file to make the adjustment that removes the leap seconds. But those details aren't really relevant to your program's runtime library because it gets its information from a service that has already filtered out the leap seconds.

So, as far as runtime libraries are concerned, a timestamp is not really a measure of the *actual* number of milliseconds that have passed since the Epoch date. Rather, it is the number of milliseconds you have to add to the Epoch date to obtain the current date and time. The difference is that, as you pointed out, we assume a fixed number of milliseconds per day, ignoring the leap seconds.

Comment: This addresses the leap seconds. But what about the rest? Is that just division and counting?

Comment: @amflare Yes. It's a bunch of simple arithmetic, complicated by leap year silliness.